# How to get every third record from a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector:

```
> dput(rn, 20)
c(128L, 241L, 354L, 467L, 580L, 693L, 806L, 919L, 1032L, 1145L, 
1258L, 1371L, 1484L, 1597L, 1710L, 1823L, 1936L, 2049L, 2162L, 
2275L)
```

How do I get every third record from this vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `seq` to create a sequence of index numbers:

```
> rn[seq(3, 20, 3)]
[1]  354  693 1032 1371 1710 2049
```

---

This works because `seq` generates the following sequence:

```
seq(from=3, to=20, by=3)
[1]  3  6  9 12 15 18
```

More generally, if you don't know the length of your vector in advance, you can calculate it using `length`:

```
seq(from=3, to=length(rn), by=3)
[1]  3  6  9 12 15 18
```

---

See `?seq` for more help.

Comment: Haha... we are definitely in some kind of R-question-answering synchronization. +1 for beating me by a few seconds (and curses upon the 30-char limit)!

Answer (score 6):

Let recycling do it's magic.

```
rn[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)]
```

though this (and all the other answers, I think) fails with `length(rn) < 3`. Maybe

```
rn[3L * seq_len(length(rn)/3L)]
```

Answer (score 3):

`rn[seq(3,length(rn),3)] # 30 chars`

Answer (score 2):

Mayby like this?

```
> x <- c(128L, 241L, 354L, 467L, 580L, 693L, 806L, 919L, 1032L, 1145L, 
+ 1258L, 1371L, 1484L, 1597L, 1710L, 1823L, 1936L, 2049L, 2162L, 
+ 2275L)
> 
> x[seq(3, length(x), 3)]
[1]  354  693 1032 1371 1710 2049
```

Answer (score 1):

`seq()` by itself does nice things: `x[seq(x)%%3==0]` will do the trick.  Technically `x[seq_along(x)%%3==0]` is faster, but most of the time you won't care.

For example,

```
> letters[seq(letters)%%3==0]
[1] "c" "f" "i" "l" "o" "r" "u" "x"
```